# Is it possible to control window management in Gnome Shell using D-Bus?

Tags: gnome, x11, window-manager, desktop-environment, d-bus

I would like to programmatically be able to communicate with the Window Manager in Gnome 3, using D-Bus.
The tasks I would like to accomplish are:

- listening for new windows
- get window flags (e.g. skip pager flag)
- get X window IDs
- maximise, minimise windows
- raise, lower windows
- hide
  windows
  The aim is to create an task-bar-like application.

I know of tools such as [xdotools](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/#id270150) or [wmctrl](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/&ei=GuLzTsaFNYWC8gO5gNnMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHOhoM3puV0sXsh-lydNFO_n66xMA), but those are very thorough tools: there are no listeners to find out if new windows have been instantiated / mapped, the latte works with window title strings.

I also tried using python-xlib, but lack of documentation or too technical documentation have made it very difficult to achieve anything.

It seems D-Bus would be appropriate for such actions. Can I use D-Bus to do this, is there a way to do this using Python? Could you provide examples?

Comment: check devilspie and devilspie2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a D-Bus-to-X11 interface in order to do this. There is no such thing.

Comment: Ok, so how do you listen to newly mapped windows, as with a new pop-up for instance? And what API would you use? Is a xdotool good enough to build a shell or do you need to use python-xlib perse?